# Backpack for Laravel CSS issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, laravel-6

I have installed Laravel Base and Laravel CRUD. Everything was alright when I was using the Laravel base only. But after installing Laravel CRUD, everything has been shattered. I am pretty new to Backpack for Laravel, so I am not sure what is going on, or maybe I have missed any step while installing.

I inspected the element and found that elements are not picking the CSS defined by `_all_skins.min.css` in AdminLTE, for example.

```
<aside class="main-sidebar">
```

The class mentioned in this element is picking CSS defined by adminLte but not picking the CSS defined in _all_skins.min.css. I am using it with Laravel 6.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backpack/Base is only used in Backpack v3.
Starting with Backpack v4, Base is no longer required.

1. **Uninstall Backpack/Base** - everything it provides is now included in Backpack/CRUD.
2. **Clear all cache using**:

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

Hope it helps.
Cheers!